# Kivy (kv-lang): Using custom properties in canvas instructions

Tags: python, canvas, properties, kivy, kivy-language

#### Background

Say I want to create a custom-styled Label with a random color backgroun (example taken from the [Kivy wiki](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Community-Guidelines#asking-for-help-on-kivy-and-kivy-users)). I do

```
#:import rand_float random.uniform

<-CustomLabel>:
        bg_color: [rand_float(0.3, 0.7) for _ in range(3)]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: self.bg_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

However, when I try to use it, I get

```
 ...
      15:    canvas.before:
      16:        Color:
 >>   17:            rgb: self.bg_color
      18:        Rectangle:
      19:            pos: self.pos
 ...
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This wouldn’t happen if the property was a simple list, e.g. `[1, 0, 0]`, so I guess properties that are bound are initialised only after `Canvas` instructions are run.

To bypass that, I can either do a `rgb: self.bg_color if self.bg_color else [0, 0, 0]` trick – but that gets really noisy really fast – or I can do

```py
class CustomLabel(Label):
    bg_color = ListProperty([0, 0, 0])
```

inside the Python file, which fixes the problem.

#### Question

How can I use custom properties inside `canvas` if I want to override `Label` directly? I.e., how can I get this to work (without checking if the property exists, as mentioned above)?

```py
# pylint: disable=no-name-in-module,no-member

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'log_level', 'debug')

from kivy.app import App  # noqa: E402
from kivy.lang import Builder  # noqa: E402


KV = """
#:import rand_float random.uniform

<-Label>:
    bg_color: [rand_float(0.3, 0.7) for _ in range(3)]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: self.bg_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


Label:
    text: 'A label'
"""


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: You can probably hack this to work by modifying the Label class before loading the kv, but you'd need to experiment with how properties are created. I'm not sure there's a neat solution, except don't do that - there shouldn't be any need to apply this kind of modification to builtin classes.

Comment: @inclement The rationale is to a) be able to style buttons consistently, even where Button is used by default, e.g. in Settings, and b) not having to rewrite the entire .kv file of the app with s/Button/Custom/Button.

Also, since my custom style is animated with different layers, I don’t want to calculate the offset at 3 different places so I’m looking for a way to use a variable.